# Mapping binary relation to first order logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I am self-learning my way through this topic and appreciate help with red marked questions.

[image]
[image]

For (c), I am stuck in thinking, if nothing is mapped to nothing, what is it? Potentially **empty**?

But (h) I find it even trickier as I do not really understand how to interpret. My best guess so far is it is describing **self-mapped set**?

Comment: (c) Yes, it is empty; in set-theoretical terms $R = \{ (a,b) \mid aRb \} = \emptyset$.

Comment: (h) $R$ it is for sure total; the formula amounts to: $a=b \to aRb$ and $a=a$ holds for every $a$. Thus, $R$ is defined on all $A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, can we do this slower please for (h)? I read in plain terms: part 1) for all a in A and for all b in B. there is a relation from A to B. This makes it total. But second part of $OR$ where it says $a \neq b$ is confusing to me, given that a, b are members of opposite sides of the relations and a comparison here is unusual!